# GET API_Link net::ERR_FAILED -------- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

im trying to get an API from openweathermap.org but im still getting the error:

> - **GET API_Link net::ERR_FAILED**
> - **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch**

here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Form from './components/form'
import Forecast from './components/forecast'




const App = (props) => {
  const api_key = 'b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22';
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState("")
  const [humidity, setHumidity] = useState("")
  const [city, setCity] = useState("")


const getWeather = async (e) => {
  console.log('jj')
  const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
  e.preventDefault();
  const api_call = await fetch(`https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${api_key}`);
  const response = await api_call.json();
  console.log('jj')
  if(city){
    setTemperature(response.main.temp)
    setHumidity(response.main.humidity)
    setCity(response.name)
  }else{
    setError('please fill out input error')
  }

}
return (
  <div>
<Form loadWeather={getWeather}/>
<Forecast 
temperature={temperature}
humidity={humidity}
city={city}
error = {error}/>
  </div>
)
}
```

i did it with other apis there was no problem

Comment: use await fetch in try catch block and then solve your error according to error message

Comment: Look in your browswer dev tools (preferably chrome). There is a network tab that may give you more information of the error and the console tab. My guess is that it will be a [cors problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)